# How to: Get version image dimensions carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

This is my uploader:

```
class PostImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper
  storage :fog
  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:

  def store_dir
    "uploads/posts"
  end

  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_limit => [280, nil]
    process :convert => 'jpg'
  end

  def filename
   random_token = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{model.id.to_s}").first(20)
   ivar = "@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"    
   token = model.instance_variable_get(ivar)
   token ||= model.instance_variable_set(ivar, random_token)
   "#{model.title.gsub(" ", "-").downcase}-#{token}.jpg" if original_filename
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  process :store_dimensions

  private

  def store_dimensions
    if file && model.post_image.medium.present?
     model.image_width, model.image_height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
    end
  end 

end
```

in this tutorial, https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Get-image-dimensions, it is possible to get original image dimensions. But I want to get version image dimensions. Something like this:

```
def store_dimensions
        if file && model.post_image.medium.present?
         model.image_width, model.image_height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(model.post_image.medium)[:dimensions]
        end
      end
```

Instead of `file.file`, `model.post_image.medium`.

The problem is that this code works when the object has been created previously. Only it works when update the image.

I need that this code works when I create it the first time.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `callbacks` instead. https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-use-callbacks

```
after :store, :store_dimensions

# rest of uploader codes...    

def store_dimensions(file)
  model.image_width, model.image_height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(model.post_image.medium)[:dimensions]
  model.save!
end
```

Comment: With medium version does works fine. However with: `version :medium do
    process :resize_to_limit => [870, nil]
    process :convert => 'jpg'
  end` i get  `403 Forbidden` from amazon. When I try resize a big image with more dimensions i got this problem. Thank you